# Strategy: Specify number of bars used for backtesting?

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to apply my strategy only to the last, say, 100 bars or so?
I though `max_bars_back` did just that, but no matter how I try, it still use many many more bars than I want. I am using the following:

```
strategy(title = "My Script", shorttitle="MyScript", precision=0, max_bars_back=100)
```

Or is it possible to only use the bars that are in current view as input data for my script? That would be even better.

Comment: There's no such functionality yet. Only some workarounds like `if time > timestamp(_some_start_date) and time < timestamp(_some_end_date) doStrategy()`. `max_bars_back` only sets how far your code can look into history and in most cases you don't need it because usually pine detects that length corectly.

Comment: http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#debugging here's more info in the `How do I implement date range filtering in strategies?` paragraph

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for backtest date:

```
// Backtest Input
FromYear = input(2015, "Backtest Start Year")
FromMonth = input(1, "Backtest Start Month")
FromDay = input(1, "Backtest Start Day")
ToYear = input(2999, "Backtest End Year")
ToMonth = input(1, "Backtest End Month")
ToDay = input(1, "Backtest End Day")

// Backtest Setting
start     = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00)  // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false
```

The, add: and window() in your strategy like this:

```
strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, when = long and window())
```

You should be ok to change it to bars instead of dates I guess.